# delete duplicate entries in a particular comma sep fields per line

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv

so my file has formatted  like this i.e tab separated columns with csv per column

```
        1 B,B,B,B  C,C,C,C  D,D,D,D

        2 A,A,A,A  B,B,B,B  E,E,E,E
```

I would like to remove the duplicates from each filed but in a line by line manner, where each line duplicates are treated independently.

so the output should be

```
1 B C D
2 A B E
```

Comment: do you have some code? Seems like homework

Comment: well i have a file , and I have seen people using  awk and sort , but then it deletes those duplicate values from all the lines. I know if you convert a list to a set in python you can get rid of the duplicates. but I wanted a linux option with awk or sort

Comment: Show the code or we can't help you.

Comment: I have no code , as I  dotn know where to start.

Comment: how this line `1 B,B,A,B C,D,C,F D,D,G,D` should be processed?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html

Also, as Roman mentioned I would expect proper input and expected output. This is not clear on the post

Comment: so its a tab seperated file , with each column having comma seperated values

Comment: sorry line(n) not part of the file.I will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `distinct` (aka `uniq`) from the perl [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.419/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#uniq_LIST) module

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=distinct -alne '
  print join " ", map { join ",", distinct split "," } @F
' yourfile
1 B C D

2 A B E
```

If you want tab-separated output, change the first `join " "` to `join "\t"`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -Ee 's/([^,\t]*,?)+/\1/g' yourfile
```

We are using GNU sed here.

```
1       B       C       D
2       A       B       E
```

Comment: thank  you! do you mind explaining the code and also can I pipe the output to another file? As it would help me for future code

Comment: `sed -Ee 's/([^,\t]*)(,\1)*/\1/' yourfile` (Untested as I am away from a terminal). We single out chunks `[^,\t]*` read as contiguous collection of not-comma,not-tab which is followed by comma and the chunk multiple times: this whole thing is replaced just by the chunk, which we had saved in the first pair of brackets ( ... ) and later recalled as \1. Note: this presupposes that the chunks are of the same kind. Since you had not told what to do when differing chunks are bracketed together, e.g., AAA,AAA,BBB. Yes you can use the output of this as in put to the next command.

Answer (score 0):

***Python*** solution (tested on Python 3.5):

***del_duplicates.py*** script:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:      # reading the file (passed in via command line)
    lines = f.read().splitlines()      # split the file into list of lines
    for l in lines:                    # for each line
        items = l.split('\t')          # split line by tab `\t`
        for k,i in enumerate(items):   # processing fields
            if k > 0: items[k] = ','.join(set(i.split(',')))  # getting unique values via set object
        print('\t'.join(items))        # join separate fields back into straight line
```

Usage:

```
python del_duplicates.py yourfile
```

The output:

```
1   B   C   D
2   A   B   E
```

Answer (score 0):

With (mostly) bash:

The input file (adding a line to see what happens with non-homogenous fields.

```
1   B,B,B,B C,C,C,C D,D,D,D
2   A,A,A,A B,B,B,B E,E,E,E
3   L,M,M   N,O,N   X,Y,Z
```

A function to remove duplicates from a delimiter-separated word. I'm using parentheses for the function body to isolate changes to `$IFS` into a subshell. Leaving `$2` unquoted is the magic here.

```
uniqify() (
    IFS=$1
    printf "%s\n" $2 | sort -u | paste -sd"$1"
)
```

To process the file.

```
while read -ra words; do 
    for word in "${words[@]}"; do 
        uniqify , "$word"
    done | paste -s
done < input
```

Output

```
1   B   C   D
2   A   B   E
3   L,M N,O X,Y,Z
```